# Using pandas apply with dates and dates shifted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with dates below:

```
               Daycount   
Date                                                                       
2020-05-01         0      
2020-06-01         0        
2020-07-01         0          
2020-08-01         0         
2020-09-01         0
```

I'm trying to extract the daycount from one day to the next using the below formula:

```
def days360(start_date, end_date, method_eu=False):
        start_day = start_date.day
    start_month = start_date.month
    start_year = start_date.year
    end_day = end_date.day
    end_month = end_date.month
    end_year = end_date.year

    if start_day == 31 or (method_eu is False and start_month == 2 and (start_day == 29 or (start_day == 28 and calendar.isleap(start_year) is False))):
        start_day = 30

    if end_day == 31:
        if method_eu is False and start_day != 30:
            end_day = 1

            if end_month == 12:
                end_year += 1
                end_month = 1
            else:
                end_month += 1
        else:
            end_day = 30

    return end_day + end_month * 30 + end_year * 360 - start_day - start_month * 30 - start_year * 360
```

However, I tried using the apply function as follow, yet I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

When passing just one set of values within the DataFrame it works so my formula is definitely correct. Creating another columns with the dates shifted and then applying the formula did work, but I'm looking for a cleaner way. I'm not sure about the apply function though. I'm supposed to get 30 days for all the daycount.

```
hypo["Daycount"] = hypo.apply(lambda x: days360(x.index,x.index.shift(-1)))
```

Target output should be table below:

```
        Date  Daycount
0 2020-05-01      30.0
1 2020-06-01      30.0
2 2020-07-01      30.0
3 2020-08-01      30.0
4 2020-09-01      30.0
```

Comment: Added target output.

Comment: Providing the error message would help. I think the offending code is the way you use index.shift . Check the df.index.shift method signature - it has two arguments, periods and freq (defaults to None, the index's freq is used), but if your index has no freq attribute set you will get an error,  you might need to specify freq='D' and check if your your DatetimeIndex index has got the freq attribute set

Comment: My frequency is based on 'MS', adding that to the shift function gives the same error as posted above. "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: What's your logic of counting the day count. I guess the daycount should be  `[0, 31.0, 30.0, 31.0, 31.0]`.

Comment: okey, it is clearer now, the x.index and the shifted one is indeed an array and when passed by apply to your function as arguments would cause problems for the if, so the reason for the error is understandable, now just to find the way to fix it ..

Comment: @ShubhamSharma My daycount is based on 360 days in a year. However there is a mistake indeed and the first one should be 0 as i shifted by -1 instead of 1, although this shouldn't be problem. In the end i have to get 30 for all the daycounts, or -30 if i shift correctly as you point out.

Comment: That means you are considering all the months  have to be 30 days. Right?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Correct, it's for simplicity to calculate interest rates and mortgage payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert a series to datetime like series then use [`Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) to access datetime properties of series, then use [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) on components `year`, `month` & `day` to get the desired results:

```
df = df.reset_index()
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Daycount'] = (
    (dates.dt.year.diff() * 360 + dates.dt.month.diff() * 30 + dates.dt.day.diff()).fillna(0)
)
```

---

```
# print(df)
         Date  Daycount
0  2020-05-01       0.0
1  2020-06-01      30.0
2  2020-07-01      30.0
3  2020-08-01      30.0
4  2020-09-01      30.0
```

---

Consider another example with a more sophisticated dataframe:

```
# Given dataframe
# print(df)
            Daycount
Date                
2020-05-01         0
2020-06-03         0
2020-07-01         0
2021-07-02         0
2022-08-03         0
```

---

```
# Desired result
# print(df)
         Date  Daycount
0  2020-05-01       0.0
1  2020-06-03      32.0
2  2020-07-01      28.0
3  2021-07-02     361.0
4  2022-08-03     391.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `.apply` you need to modify your function (or add another one based on the one you already have) to operate on Series objects (not their elements). See the pandas DataFrame apply docstring "Objects passed to the function are Series objects whose index is
either ..."

You can avoid using .apply and lambda by using list comprehension

```
df['derived'] = [ yourfunction(a,b) for a,b in zip(df.index, df.index.shift(-1)) ]
```

I am sure there is another way to vectorize your function but this at least should make your code work. There was a time when lambda expression were strongly opposed by key person of python and advocated to be removed as it can always be done another way.